# ¿Que implica, causa, y como evitar que en el editor de VBA se vea repetidamente el nombre de VBAProject(LibroN.xlsx)

Tags: vba

Tengo un libro que tiene macros y que abre otros libros que NO  tienen macros(generalmente).
En el editor de VBA se ve:

```
VBAProject(LibroMacros.xlsm)
```

Cuando lanzo una de las macros, que abre otros libros, en el explorador de proyectos puedo ver:

```
VBAProject(LibroMacros.xlsm)
VBAProject(Libro1.xlsx)
VBAProject(Libro2.xlsx)
```

Esperaría que cuando cierro los libros los proyectos:

```
VBAProject(Libro1.xlsx)
VBAProject(Libro2.xlsx)
```

Desaprecieran.
Pues no es así.
No solo no es así, si no que además se repiten sus nombres en el explorador de proyectos de tal forma que se ve:

```
VBAProject(LibroMacros.xlsm)
VBAProject(Libro1.xlsx)
VBAProject(Libro1.xlsx)
VBAProject(Libro1.xlsx)
VBAProject(Libro2.xlsx)
VBAProject(Libro2.xlsx)
VBAProject(Libro2.xlsx)
```

¿Por qué se produce lo que supongo  que es un error y cómo o donde buscar la causa para corregirlo?

Comment: Pues imagino que la causa y/o dónde buscar es... en los macros que afirmas que tienes pero no podemos ver. Es difícil responder a una pregunta completamente a ciegas.

Comment: Gracias Benito-B.
También yo lo supongo.
Los libros se abren ( open), asignan y cierran (close) y aún así quedan en el editor.
Lo que necesito es una pista para ver qué y donde buscar.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: en que editor hablas?

Comment: Hola gbianchi. Editor VBA.
Creía que saldrían del editor, cuando se cerraran, con  macros o a  clic.
No es así. Si los abro a golpe de clic, cuando los cierro a golpe de clic no se cierran en el explorador/editor de proyectos...hasta que se cierra el último y entonces se cierran todos.
Alguno se cierre guardándoles antes, cuando el sistema, pregunta si los guardo o no.
Con macro, si no les modifico, no les guardo, y se quedan en el editor. 
Si doy de nuevo orden de abrirlos, crea de nuevo otra vez el proyecto de ese libro, con lo cual lo puedo tener 3-4 veces el proyecto de ese libro.

Comment: [edito, mi respuesta era general]

Comment: Yo entiendo que no es un error en si, aunque lo parezca. Cada vez que carga un fichero, genera un modulo con su nombre en memoria y de alguna manera la instancia de la carga permanece ahi, en el editor VBA. Por cierto, supongo que la carga de ficheros la haces desde VBA? Usas Application.ScreenUpdating? Igual ayuda a que la lista de proyectos se actualice.

Comment: pcandido...me parece normal, como a tí, el que cargue el fichero en el editor de VBA al abrirlo, y que lo haga tantas veces como se abra ese fichero, pero también me parecería normal el que cada vez que se cierre desapareciera del editor de forma tal que solo se viera una única instancia del proyecto.
Aún no he conseguido ver mi error, porque pienso que debe serlo. ni la lógica que causa el que no se descargue.
Los ficheros por los que he preguntado, los abro generalmente desde VBA.
Utilizo, casi siempre, ScreenUpdating, calculo y EnableEvents  ( antes y despues del sub)